# How to compare the Wifi SSID to specific String

Tags: android, string

I am trying to compare the SSID of the connected wifi to the one I want it connect to. So I am using the following code:

```
WifiInfo wifiInfo = returnedWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID().toString();
if (ssid.equalsIgnoreCase("MarkV")) {
   Toast.makeText(WalkitalkiMainActivity.this,
         "Connected to: " + ssid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

when I debug, I find the right SSID name, but the Toast inside the if statement never execute.
What is the problem ?

Comment: change ur if statement to (ssid.equalsIgnoreCase("MarkV"))

Comment: @mtetno Isn't that just a shorter version of what OP has already written?

Comment: @mtetno: Still not working !! .. and this does not really highlights the issue as the two statements are similar, aren't they ?!

Comment: i had a doubt so asked to change ..did loged ssid string? what is it gioving? and why eualsIgnoreCase compare?

Comment: @mtetno: when Debug stops at line 3, the "ssid" string value is: MarkV. The "equalsIgnoreCase" is not mandatory, but I thought it might help better than just "equals".

Comment: ok strange isssue but just a sugestion do : log.d("tag",ssid.equalsIgnoreCase("MarkV")); tell me what it prints true or flase?

Comment: @mtetno: the log.d takes Strings arguments only .. So, I executed "Log.d("tag",wifiInfo.getSSID());", the output id: MarkV.

Comment: ohh u could hv written `log.d("tag",ssid.equalsIgnoreCase("MarkV")+" output");`

Comment: @mtetno: Sorry for the delay and for not being creative in solving this small String-argument issue :-( , but the output is "false" ..

Comment: ohh u got the point now? did u solve?

Comment: @mtetno: thanks a lot :-) I got the point.. but still can't work out how to solve it as the SSID is clearly "MarkV" and that shows in line 2 when debugging. It just doesn't work and the logic doesn't make sense .. I am going crazy, howcome two similar Strings are not equal ?!!

Comment: @mtetno: GOT IT finally .. to explain: the captured SSID is not "MarkV", no, it is ""MarkV"", did you notice the additional double quotations .. The comparison involves all the captured string stream which in this case is not "MarkV" but ""MarkV"" .. thank you anyway for the guidance .

Comment: right i had same point but was still not sure ..anyways nice u solved

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution to this problem. The reason is ssid has double quotation marks around it. So you have to check like this.

```
if(ssid.equals("\"MarkV\"")){//or ssid.equalsIgnoreCase("\"MarkV\"")
    //Do
}
else{
    //Else do
}
```